# Is a so-called $n$-fold almost split extension equivalent to an $n$-almost split sequence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

In *Martinéz-Villa, Roberto; Solberg, Øyvind*, [**Artin–Schelter regular algebras and categories**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2010.06.006), Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra 215, No. 4, 546-565 (2011), [ZBL1238.16023](https://zbmath.org/1238.16023), the authors give a definition of "$n$-fold almost split extension" before Proposition 2.4 as follows:

> To this end recall that a non-zero $n$-fold extension $\eta$ in $\text{Ext}^n_\lambda(C, A)$ is called an $n$-fold almost split extension if for any non-splittable epimorphism $f\colon X\to C$ and for any non-splittable monomorphism $g\colon A\to Y$ the pullback $\eta\cdot f$ and the pushout $g\cdot \eta$ are both zero in $\text{Ext}^n_\Lambda(X, A)$ and $\text{Ext}^n_\Lambda(C, Y)$, respectively.

Here $\Lambda$ is a generalized Artin-Schelter regular algebra defined in the article, which is two-sided Noetherian, has finite global dimension and satisfies some further conditions. I wonder whether the definition of an $n$-fold almost split extension is equivalent to the definition of an $n$-almost split sequence given by Iyama at Definition 3.1 in his famous paper *Iyama, Osamu*, [**Higher-dimensional Auslander-Reiten theory on maximal orthogonal subcategories.**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2006.06.002), Adv. Math. 210, No. 1, 22-50 (2007). [ZBL1115.16005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1115.16005).

For the case $n=1$, at least with the assumption that $A$ and $C$ are indecomposable, it's easy to show a 1-fold almost split extension is exactly an almost split sequence, using universal properties of pullback and pushout. But for the higher case, is there some conditions such that the two definitions coincide?

Comment: I can't find the first definition in Jasso and Kvamme's paper. Are you sure that you're linking to the right paper?

Comment: Very sorry, it's Martinéz-Villa amd Solberg's. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly the relationship between the two definitions, but they're not the same, as the first one depends only on the class in $\operatorname{Ext}^n_\Lambda(C,A)$ but the second doesn't.

For example, if $n=3$ and $0\to X\to Y\to Z\to0$ is a nonsplit short exact sequence, then taking the direct sum with
$$0\to0\to X\to Y\to Z\to0\to0$$
does not affect whether
$$0\to A\to B_1\to B_2\to B_3\to C\to 0$$
satisfies the first definition, but
$$0\to A\to B_1\oplus X\to B_2\oplus Y\to B_3\oplus Z\to C\to 0$$
will never satisfy the second definition.